# Nginx get Ssl certificate ca.crt contents with Lua

Tags: ssl, nginx, lua, verify

I want to get contents of Ssl crt files which is sent by client but I can't get contents of Ssl .crt files. How can I do this with Lua.

My aim is parsing contents of ca.crt and take some information for comparation.

Nginx configuration is ok for authentication but Lua part is missing...